# Refer to object in another class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I simply want to code in 'didSimulatePhysics()' to get the shark to go in the opposite direction when it reaches the end of the screen. But I can not get Swift to find the shark when I try to use it in the 'didSimulatePhysics()'

**GameElementsClass:**

```
import SpriteKit

 extension GameScene {

    func createSharkAtPosition (position:CGPoint, ofType type:SharkType) -> SharkNode {

        let node = SharkNode()
        let position = CGPoint(x: position.x * scaleFactor, y: position.y)
        node.position = position
        node.name = "SHARKNODE"
        node.sharkType = type
        var sprite:SKSpriteNode


        sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shark1")

        node.addChild(sprite)

        node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: sprite.size)
        node.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        node.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        node.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(-60)

        node.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionBitMask.Shark
        node.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0


        return node
    }
}
```

**GameSceneClass:**

```
func sharkMaker() {
    let randomXPos = arc4random_uniform(170) + 10
    let yPosition = CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 200 * CGFloat(counter)
    counter += 1
    let shark = createSharkAtPosition(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomXPos), y:    yPosition - 180), ofType: SharkType.normalShark)
    foreground.addChild(shark)

}


 override func didSimulatePhysics() {

    if node.position.x < -10 {
        node.xScale =  -1
        node.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(50)
    }else if (node.position.x > self.size.width + 10) {
        node.xScale = 1
        node.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(-50)
    }
```

Comment: You should create your shark from your gamescene.

Comment: want to add the code down below in didSimulatePhysics(). but i cant seem to work it out

`if player.position.x < -10 {
            shark.xScale = shark.xScale * -1
            shark.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(60)
        }else if (player.position.x > self.size.width + 10) {
            shark.xScale = shark.xScale
            shark.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = CGFloat(-60)
        }`

Comment: You need to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36320205/edit).  Right now it's unclear.  We have just a vague description of what you are trying to do.  You haven't created an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Learning a little bit about [object-oriented programming](http://importblogkit.com/2015/04/programming-objectively/) will go a long way.

Comment: Just edited the whole post to make it more clear what i try to do here.

I simply want to code in 'didSimulatePhysics()' to get the shark to go in the opposite direction when it reaches the end of the screen. But I can not get Swift to find the shark when I try to use it in the 'didSimulatePhysics()'

Answer (score 0):

The `shark` variable is local to `sharkMaker`, I suppose your code don't compile, or? Either use a property to store the shark or name it `shark.name="Sharky" and then use`let shark = childNodeByName("Sharky")` to find it somewhere in your hierarchy.

Comment: Just edited the 'didSimulatePhysics()' again.
 shark = node in this case. I want to be able to use the node outside the 'GameElementsClass' and use it in the 'didSimulatePhysics'.
Setting 'node.name = "Sharky"' and then use it in 'GameElementsClass'  does not seem to work, nothing happens.
Any other suggestions? Thank you